# Rolling out update of SDK OTA

Tags: android, sdk, android-sdk-tools

I have developed a SDK for android applications.We have many clients using this SDK in there applications.Now i have updated my SDK.I am looking for a way that these changes can reflect in there application without updating there app on play store.Urgent help needed.Any help will be appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you can dynamically load a jar file from your SD card using DexLoader class...which you can update when ever you want..on your storage... below is working code..

```
  final String libPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +     "/test.jar";
    final File tmpDir = getDir("dex", 0);

    final DexClassLoader classloader = new DexClassLoader(libPath, tmpDir.getAbsolutePath(), null, this.getClass().getClassLoader());
    final Class<Object> classToLoad = (Class<Object>) classloader.loadClass("com.test.android.MainActivity");

    final Object myInstance  = classToLoad.newInstance();
    final Method doSomething = classToLoad.getMethod("doSomething");



    doSomething.invoke(myInstance);
```

and in your library file code can be like this

```
public class MainActivity {



public void doSomething() {

Log.e(MainActivity .class.getName(), "MainActivity : doSomething() called.");
}}
```

tell me if you need any assistance

Answer (score 1):

there is no such way for your situation. But there is one thing you can do to enable it for next update. Android can dynamically load compiled code with [DexClassLoader](http://developer.android.com/reference/dalvik/system/DexClassLoader.html). So you compile a new DEX file, and then force your SDK to download and use it.

```
// Internal storage where the DexClassLoader writes the optimized dex file to
  final File optimizedDexOutputPath = getDir("outdex", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  DexClassLoader cl = new DexClassLoader(dexInternalStoragePath.getAbsolutePath(),
                                         optimizedDexOutputPath.getAbsolutePath(),
                                         null,
                                         getClassLoader());
  Class libProviderClazz = null;
  try {
      // Load the library.
      libProviderClazz =
          cl.loadClass("com.example.dex.lib.LibraryProvider");
      // Cast the return object to the library interface so that the
      // caller can directly invoke methods in the interface.
      // Alternatively, the caller can invoke methods through reflection,
      // which is more verbose. 
      LibraryInterface lib = (LibraryInterface) libProviderClazz.newInstance();
      lib.showAwesomeToast(this, "hello");
  } catch (Exception e) { ... }
```

Comment: Can you please explain it a bit more. I mean where and how to implement this code and how the flow will go. will this work over air?Thanks in advance.

Comment: @HarrySharma, https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=android%20dexclassloader%20example&es_th=1